# Need to use deduction to show $(p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor r) \implies (p \lor r)$ is a tautology

Tags: propositional-calculus

$$(p \lor q) \land (\lnot q \lor r) \implies (p \lor r)$$

My work so far:
[image: My Work So Far]

I feel like I'm doing something very wrong and making the problem get extremely tangled

Answer (score 1):

We should make use of the Implication laws directly. It simplifies the process.

Additionally, we should use this rule. Conjunction implies disjunction.
$$\begin{align} 
(a \wedge b) \implies (a \vee b) & \space \space \space\text{[E6]}
\end{align}
$$

The deductive proof scheme is as follows.
$$\begin{align} 
& (p \vee q) \wedge (\neg q \vee r) \\
1. \space & (p \vee q) \\
2. \space & (\neg q \vee r) \\
3. \space & (p \vee q) \vee (\neg q \vee r) \iff (p \vee r) & \text{[E6, Associativity]}\\
\end{align}
$$